# How to run Jmeter (.jmx) script using multiple IP addresses?

Tags: performance, proxy, load, jmeter

I have written a jmeter script for my web application which runs from single system.

What should i do so that i can run same script from some other IP addresses/systems.

I ran it on other system connected in LAN (REMOTE RUN), but it ran only on that system.

I want to run same script from multiple IPs/Systems. Is there is any setting or update we can do in jmeter so that it will run those script from a bunch of IP addresses?

Or, Can we run jmeter from some browser which uses multiple proxies ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Had a look at this already ? https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter. I assume you want to use ONE computer which uses SEVERAL different ips. If you need SEVERAL computers this is another issue ...

Comment: Yes, i wanted to use my own computer which use several different IPs.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is configured to provide several IP addresses on a certain NIC or has different NICs you can tell JMeter which IP address to use for outgoing connections.

[image]

Credits for this solution go to blazemeter, the information has been taken from their [blog](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter).

Comment: Thank you @Marged, let me try this. Will update you if i face any issues :)